# Using logical operators in Python without a condition

Tags: python, logical-operators

This seems like a simple question but I was unable to find a precedent. One answer [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-the-and-and-or-operators-work-in-Python) points it out without explaining why.

Using logical operators without two variables returns not a boolean but one of the variables - the first for `OR` and the second for `AND`.

```
'x' or 'y'
> 'x'

3 and 4
> 4
```

What's the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Make your code shorter. ``'x' or 'y'`` is shorter than ``'x' if 'x' else 'y'``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that that is the most efficient way to shortcut evaluation of boolean expressions. With `or` Python returns the first *truthy* value that it encounters. It doesn't need to evaluate the rest to discover if the expression is true. Similarly, with `and` Python returns the first *falsy* value that it encounters. It doesn't need to evaluate the rest to discover if the expression is false.

If it bothers you that you get a non-boolean back, then wrap a call to `bool()` around your expression.

Comment: Both 3 and 4 are truthy, though

Comment: @alec_a not in the boolean context of `3 and 4`.

Comment: Yes, but for `and` it returns the first *falsy* value. You can't tell if the expression is true without evaluating everything.

Comment: @lucasgcb What do you mean, not in the boolean context? if 3 returns True

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't bother me, I was just curious about the behaviour. It still seems like it would make sense to return a boolean (especially in the `AND` case), rather than returning the value it found, which is probably not what the user is interested in.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I take your point but the behaviour has been there since Python 1 (before Python even had a boolean type) and there is a lot of code out there that expects to get the last value back from `and`, so it would be hugely disruptive to change that now.